# AJAX requests to my node server - not getting through

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, https

I'm currently redirecting traffic to https on my node server:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.set('port', port);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './src/public')));

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] === "https"){
    // OK, continue
    return next();
  };
  res.redirect('https://'+req.hostname+req.url);
})

app.get('*', function( req, res ) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './src/public/index.html'));
} );

app.use(require('./server/routes/index'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function (){
    console.log('Express started on port ' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
  });

module.exports = app;
```

In doing so, my AJAX calls aren't getting through: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Of course when I remove the above redirect, my AJAX calls make it through.

I managed to find one other post on SO from someone having this issue but the suggestion was to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to accept any incoming AJAX requests, which seems like a security issue.

If I want continue to use the https redirect, is there a way to allow the AJAX calls through or do I need to turn of the redirect?

Comment: Can you try using `req.originalUrl` instead of `req.url`?

Comment: @31piy Just tried it, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use **req.protocal** and **req.get('host')** to get protocol and host url

```
 app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
      if(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] === "https"){
        // OK, continue
        return next();
      };
      res.redirect(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl);
    })
```

Comment: *I thought this was working but it actually does not get the resonse as I thought it did. It does however cause new errors net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I use a promise for my AJAX request too and I get: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.req.onerror

Comment: this error happens when webpage  redirects to another web page that redirects back to the original endlessly . this might be happening in your case also@skwny

Comment: This won't work at all. The logic here is to force ssl redirect if user visits using non ssl url. Your code forwards the url as it is, which causes a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

next accept another callback  like

`app.all(path, callback [, callback ...])`

let you hava a index page then it should like

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
      if(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] === "https"){
        // OK, continue
         next();
      };
      res.redirect(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl);
    }, index)
```

Comment: This does not work either. I have been running this locally so I pushed it to a cloud server and it won't redirect to https either. The only thing that happens is that my ajax calls attempt to redirect to https, and fail (connection refused). I updated my post to show my entire app.js file just in case I have something incorrect elsewhere.

Comment: At server side everying correct It might be port issue as know https use 433 and http we use 8080.